# TopMost property not working

Tags: c#, winforms, topmost

I have a form that when I check a box (`Duplicate #`), a form pops up (`CableID_DuplicateView`), and I want it to remain ontop until the checkbox is unchecked. However this isn't happening.

I have set the `TopMost` property to true both dynamically and statically;

```
this.TopMost = true;
this.TopMost = Checkbox.Checked;
```

But if I click on anything on the previous form, it gets shoved to the back.

[image]

How can I keep it ontop?

Note: I want the other form to still be accessible beneath the top form. And yes, this is an Mdi application, does that make a difference on the `TopMost` property?

Comment: You cannot make an MDI child window top-most.  Winforms forgets to throw an exception if you try it anyway.  Only top-level windows can be topmost.  Your MDI parent for example.  There's no obvious path forward, you'll have to re-think your UI.  Docking a control in the parent will always make it accessible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is impossible to make the windows stay on top in `MDI` system. You can try to activate the windows, so they pop on the top, but this makes only more harm to other actions. I wouldn't recommend trying that. There is just no working way to make some window `TopMost` in `MDI` configuration.

Answer (score 2):

This worked for my similar problem:

try

```
yourTopForm.TopLevel=true;
yourTopForm.TopMost=true;
yourTopForm.Show(this);
```

The overloaded  `Show(this)` funcition to show the form is the important part.

Comment: I had same problem. This solution in 100% Ok. It work like a charm!!

Answer (score 0):

Pass your parent form into the Show method of your Top Most form.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I did, like this you mean? `ShowDuplicateView(Menu_View Main_Menu, CableID_CreateView CView)`

Comment: Like this: var duplicateForm = new DuplicateForm(); duplicateForm.Show(this); //its parent form

Comment: OK, so just to clarify, My parent form is `Menu`, and my child form, `CreateView`, calls `DuplicateView` when it's checkbox is clicked.